# cookie session wordpress from an object

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies

I want to select an object and that object id must be saved in a cookie session. How do I do that in wordpress?

so far i got this

```
add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_first_cookie' );

function setting_my_first_cookie() {
  setcookie( $SeasonId, 30 * DAYS_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}


if(!isset($_COOKIE[$SeasonId])) {
  echo "The cookie: '" . $SeasonId . "' is not set.";
} else {
  echo "The cookie '" . $SeasonId . "' is set.";
  echo "Cookie is:  " . $_COOKIE[$SeasonId];
}



  unset( $_COOKIE[$SeasonId] );
  setcookie( $SeasonId, '', time() - ( 15 * 60 ) );

wp_redirect( home_url(), 302 );
exit;
```

and the object is called like this

```
echo "<td><a href='?SeasonId=".$Season->Id."'>";
        echo "$Season->DateFrom - $Season->DateTo";
        echo "</a></td>";
```

what am I doing wrong? or is there another solution

thanks

Comment: Can we see the code for the class "Season"

Answer (score 0):

this is the function for calling a list for season

```
function Season () {    
    echo "<ul class='accordion' data-accordion data-allow-all-closed='true'>";
    echo "<li id='' class='accordion-item' data-accordion-item>";
    echo "<a href='#' class='accordion-title' style='background-color:#3db7e4; padding: 1rem; color:white;'><h6><strong>Maak een keuze</strong></h6></a>";
    echo "<div class='hover accordion-content' data-tab-content>";
            echo "<table class='hover'>";
        echo "<tbody>";

    /**
     * Get list of seasons.
     */
    $Seasons    = WaterpoloAPI::call("Seasons", "getSeasons");
    $SeasonId   = "";

    foreach($Seasons as $Season) {  
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='?SeasonId=".$Season->Id."'>";
        echo "$Season->DateFrom - $Season->DateTo";
        echo "</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: it shows The cookie: '' is not set. can anyone explain why the cookie session is not working.